# Get key and values from nested dictionary from a list fortmat into a Dataframe

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have very deeply nested list of dictionaries. I am trying to capture 'keys' from specific nested dictionary and convert it to a data frame. How do I do this? I have basic dictionary knowledge to generate keys, I have tried appending `[]` and `{}` and it didn't quite work. Any guidance appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint

d = {'Main':{
            'SecondLevel':
                    [{'Identifier':'abc',
                     'StudentInfo':{'Name':'Mike','Grade':'1',
                                    'TeachersAssigned':[{'Name':'Paul'},
                                                        {'Name':'Smith'}
                                                       ]}},
                    {
                     'StudentInfo':{'Name':'Mandy','Grade':'1',
                                    'TeachersAssigned':[{'Name':'Baker'},
                                                        {'Name':'Smith'}
                                                       ]}}]}}
pprint(d)

list_dict = []
for doc in d['Main']['SecondLevel']:
    identifier = '' if doc.get('Identifier') is None else doc['Identifier']
    studentname = doc['StudentInfo']['Name']

    list_dict.append(identifier)
    list_dict.append(studentname)

    for teach in doc['StudentInfo']['TeachersAssigned']:
        teachers_name = teach['Name']

        list_dict.append(teachers_name)

pprint(list_dict)

>>> ['abc', 'Mike', 'Paul', 'Smith', '', 'Mandy', 'Baker', 'Smith']

pd.DataFrame(list_dict)
>>> single column with list of the values from above
```

I am trying to get it to like this:

```
Identifier   StudentInfo    TeachersAssigned
abc          Mike           Paul
abc          Mike           Smith
             Mandy          Baker
             Mandy          Smith
```

Am I doing the for loop wrong for list comprehension?

Comment: You'll have an issue because all columns must be of equal length in a dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your dictionary this is how I manage. But as I explained before, you cannot have columns of different length in a DataFrame, therefore you can use `np.nan`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
d = {'Main':{
            'SecondLevel':
                    [{'Identifier':'abc',
                     'StudentInfo':{'Name':'Mike','Grade':'1',
                                    'TeachersAssigned':[{'Name':'Paul'},
                                                        {'Name':'Smith'}
                                                       ]}},
                    {
                     'StudentInfo':{'Name':'Mandy','Grade':'1',
                                    'TeachersAssigned':[{'Name':'Baker'},
                                                        {'Name':'Smith'}
                                                       ]}}]}}
data = {'Identifier':[],'Name':[],'TeachersAssigned':[]}
for i in range(len(d['Main']['SecondLevel'])):
    for j in range(len(d['Main']['SecondLevel'][i]['StudentInfo']['TeachersAssigned'])):
        try: 
            data['Identifier'].append(d['Main']['SecondLevel'][i]['Identifier'])
        except KeyError:
            data['Identifier'].append(np.nan)
        data['Name'].append(d['Main']['SecondLevel'][i]['StudentInfo']['Name'])
        data['TeachersAssigned'].append(d['Main']['SecondLevel'][i]['StudentInfo']['TeachersAssigned'][j]['Name'])
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
Identifier   Name TeachersAssigned
0        abc   Mike             Paul
1        abc   Mike            Smith
2        NaN  Mandy            Baker
3        NaN  Mandy            Smith
```

Comment: Thank you so much! What does this do `d['Main']['SecondLevel'][i]['StudentInfo']['TeachersAssigned']`? What is  `[i]` mean here?

Comment: The `[i]` is the first iteration over the first list (`['SecondLevel']` contains a list of two values).